# creating new array when adding/deleting elements?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, paintcomponent

Good Evening. I am working on a program thats similar to the old game LiteBrite, where you place colored pegs on a panel and it lights up. In my program, it works similar in that when you click on the panel, it will create a new Ellipse (which ive named ColorEllipse that has specifications for location, size, and color) and that it will store it to be saved. Currently it is as an arraylist but i need it to be in a regular array. I am told the way that would be to make a new array, and copy all the contents of the old array into the new array. Now currently i use an arraylist, but unforutnately this program has specifications where we need to use a regular Array.

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LiteBritePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel{
    private final static int OFFSET = 5;
    private static int LINE_WIDTH = 2;
    private static int CELL_WIDTH = 25;


    public ArrayList <Colorable> _circles; // where ColorEllipses will be stored
    private ButtonPanel controlpanel; // used to set the color of peg that will be placed

    public LiteBritePanel() {
        this.setBackground(java.awt.Color.black);   

        _circles = new ArrayList<Colorable>();

        controlpanel = new ButtonPanel(this);
        this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(this));
        this.add(controlpanel);
    }

    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics aPaintBrush) {
        super.paintComponent(aPaintBrush);
        java.awt.Graphics2D pen = (java.awt.Graphics2D) aPaintBrush;

        java.awt.Color savedColor = pen.getColor();
        pen.setColor(java.awt.Color.black);
        for (int ball=0;ball<_circles.size();ball++)
            if(_circles.get(ball).isEmpty())
                return;
            else
                _circles.get(ball).fill(pen);
        pen.setColor(savedColor);
        this.repaint();
    }  


    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e){
        boolean foundSquare = false;

        for (int ball=0; ball < _circles.size() && !foundSquare; ball++){
            if (_circles.get(ball).contains(e.getPoint()) == true){
                foundSquare = true;
                _circles.remove(ball);
                this.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseListener extends java.awt.event.MouseAdapter {
        private LiteBritePanel _this;
        public MyMouseListener(LiteBritePanel apanel){
            _this = apanel;
        }

        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e){
            _circles.add(new ColorEllipse(controlpanel.getColor(), e.getPoint().x - (e.getPoint().x%CELL_WIDTH), e.getPoint().y - (e.getPoint().y%CELL_WIDTH), CELL_WIDTH-3,_this));
            _this.requestFocus();
            boolean foundSquare = false;
            for (int ball=0; ball < _circles.size() && !foundSquare; ball++){
                if (_circles.get(ball).contains(e.getPoint()) == true){
                    foundSquare = true;
                                // code for removing ball if one is placed
                    _this.repaint();
                }   
            }
            }
        }       
    }`
```

---

Now currently it is set as an Arraylist, but I need it to be in a regular array per this specification. then when the panel is clicked on, it adds a new ColorEllipse into that Array at that specific location (and repaints as necessary for it to show up). A later part of the program would be when i touch a peg thats already placed, it removes it, but thats for another time. right now I need to know how to increment sizes of the array and copy its contents into it. Would anyone be able to tell me what I should change?

Answer (score 1):

To copy arrays, you could use the System.arraycopy(...) method ([System API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)):

```
public static void arraycopy(
         Object src,
         int srcPos,
         Object dest,
         int destPos,
         int length)
```

where you would first create a destination array, perhaps twice as big as the the source array, and pass the old array, the starting index (0), the new array, the destination starting index (0), the length (length of old array), and it should do the rest.

Also you don't want to call repaint inside of paintComponent, trust me. Use a Swing Timer instead. There's a good tutorial on this that Google can help you find.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your board is you can just create an array that has the same size as your board. Alternatively you can do as Hovercraft suggested but it all depends on whether you want to trade cpu for memory.

```
int MAX_POSSIBLE_ELEMENTS = ...
Colorable[] _circles = new Colorable[MAX_POSSIBLE_ELEMENTS];
....rest of code...
```

Notice that the maximum number depends on the height and width of the board so you should know this at compiletime.

Comment: If the OP puts a 'peg' in all of the 'holes' the array will be at the maximum size anyway. I don't personally see why the array needs to resized in the first place.

Comment: I agree, it seems like a needless optimization, worst case scenario is that he will have to fill a majority ( if not the entire) board and the cost of declaring full array then is negligible.